# When I try To Update the Main Component Data from the Child Component through props i Getting this Error

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm Trying to add new member to Members so i have Component called ***AddMember.Vue*** and it has a form to create new member data
when i try to back these data (which i wrote it in the form input) using props and refs to update the data i getting an error can i Get some Help?
the Script code of ***AddMember.Vue***

```
    <script>
export default {
  props: { members: { type: Array } },
  methods: {
    addMember() {
      
      const newMember = {
        id: this.$refs.id.value,
        age: this.$refs.age.value,
        job: this.$refs.job.value,
        email: this.$refs.email.value,
        name: this.$refs.name.value,
      };
      this.members.push(newMember);
      this.$emit("newMember", this.members);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

and the code App.vue is

```
    <template>
  <router-view :members="members" @newMember="refreashMembers"></router-view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      members: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Mohamed Mujahid",
          age: 25,
          job: "front-end Developer",
          email: "mohamed.mojahead@gmail.com",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Mujahid Ali",
          age: 20,
          job: "Back-end Developer",
          email: "mohamed.mojahead@gmail.com",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Ahmed Mujahid",
          age: 23,
          job: "Sofwear Developer",
          email: "mohamed.mojahead@gmail.com",
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Sara Ali",
          age: 35,
          job: "IT Manager",
          email: "mohamed.mojahead@gmail.com",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    refreashMembers(members) {
      this.members = members;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

and the error is:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpEPI.png)

Comment: This `props: [{ members: { type: Array } }],` is not proper Props Syntax.
Either use a String Array (i.e., `props: ['members']`) or the object syntax (i.e., `props: { members: { type: Array } }`.
Also you're emitting your "new Member" event before a member is even added.
Shouldn't you push the new member to your array first and *then* emit the event after the new member has been added? Otherwise your code makes little to no sense to me.

Comment: thanks I edited it but i still have another error

Comment: Failed to compile.

./src/components/AddMember.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

F:\working on\vuex-app\src\components\AddMember.vue
  78:7  error  Unexpected mutation of "members" prop  vue/no-mutating-props

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Comment: Yeah makes sense that vue would complain about changing the prop.
Instead of pushing the data to the props do this:
`const newMember = {
        id: this.$refs.id.value,
        age: this.$refs.age.value,
        job: this.$refs.job.value,
        email: this.$refs.email.value,
        name: this.$refs.name.value,
      };
this.$emit('newMember', [...this.members, newMember]);`

Comment: Amazing thank you you are amazing too

Comment: No Problem, glad I could help you :)